# Facebook Like Box for Mobile Web?

Tags: facebook, jquery-mobile, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox

Just curious as I've tried to work this out, realizing the futility of working with iFrames.  I've a client who insists on having his businesses facebook like box on his mobile site, as it's his main method of updating fans and followers of the business's happenings.

The main issue is the streaming content caps out at a height of 395px with no scrolling capability on mobile, thus it avails only a few of the latest entries and hides the rest.

Anyone know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace it with a combination of a Facebook like button, and code that reads and displays the Fan Page feed using the [graph api's page's feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) connection (/pageId/feed).